# How to draw a use case digram for a autonomous system?

Tags: use-case

I'm developing a real-time fraud detection system for a bank. The job of this fraud detection system is to decide whether the incoming transaction is fraud or not. The system has no interaction with the banking customer. The fraud detection system has use cases like capture incoming transaction data, calculate the risk level of the transaction, etc.

How to draw a use case diagrams for this type of a situation?

Comment: Are you concerned about what would be the actors to define the triggers for your particular use cases?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The Use cases need to be triggered whenever a user makes a transaction.

Comment: Well you stated _"The system has no interaction with the banking customer. "_, and also that there are _"incoming transactions"_. Thus the actor should be the system that handles those.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The fraud detection system is a part of an Online Banking Application. Therefore the user interacts with the Online Banking application, not with the fraud detection system. That's why I stated that "_The system has no interaction with the banking customer_"

Comment: I really don't want to put rain on top of your project, but a banking application is one of those softwares that is very risky and demands a lot of experience and knowledge to make right. You shouldn't be tackling this project without a good, experienced team, with at least one or two people with previous experience in the area.

Comment: @T.Sar I'm doing this just as a university project not for any real-world production purpose.

Comment: @ArunodaSamarasinghe Then you should probably check with your teacher.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Cases with respect to downstream systems](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/186986/use-cases-with-respect-to-downstream-systems)

Answer (score 5):

Actors in a use case diagram (or when identified in textual or tabular representations of use cases) do not need to be humans. Other systems can also be actors. The system can also be an actor that invokes use cases in other systems, but this would be indicated on a use case diagram for the other system and not your diagram for the fraud detection system.